# Todolist react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, map-function

Javascript (reactjs) beginner here, i have made a very simple todolist app using react hooks, for now when user writes something new, it just replaces old text so i need advice from you guys to how to not replace old text but have everything there, that i can see what things user has written (is it possible without any loops or map function?(you can use if its necessary)).

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [input, setValue] = useState("")
  const [something, setSomething] = useState("")

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }
  const jotain = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!input) return
    setSomething(input)
    setValue("");
    console.log(input)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <p> {something} </p>
      <form onSubmit={jotain} >
        <input placeholder="Kirjoita jotain" type="text" value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are after, can you give an example of the desired behavior?

Comment: @thedude when user writes something and press enter it goes here :  <p> {something} </p>, and when next user writes something it just goes below previous text and does not replace it (want to do it without any loops or map function if its possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to store all the inputs in an array instead of a string. Then use `map()` to render all saved todos.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [input, setValue] = useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }
  
  const jotain = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!input) return
    
    const newTodos = [...todos, input];
    
    setTodos(newTodos);
    setValue("");
  }


  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map((todo, index) => <p key={index}>{todo}</p>)}
      <form onSubmit={jotain} >
        <input placeholder="Kirjoita jotain" type="text" value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: this is what i.m looking for but is this possible without any loops or map()?

Comment: Using `map()` is actually a [recommended solution](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). Trying to write this without using loops or `map` will lead to unobvious code. Why would you like to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two new addition :

- We need to set `something` as array
- concat `something` with new value

Putting same example that you mentioned without any loop or map. You can map or style the `something` list with your choice.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [input, setValue] = useState("")
  const [something, setSomething] = useState([])

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  const jotain = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!input) return;
    setSomething(something.concat(<li>{input}</li>))
    setValue("");
    console.log(input)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <ul> {something} </ul>
      <form onSubmit={jotain} >
        <input placeholder="Kirjoita jotain" type="text" value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: when user writes for example 'olee' and second user writes 'toot', 'toot' should be under 'olee' and not replace it !

Comment: the above code doesn't replace it.. it just concat the data in line. everything is present in `something` const. you can loop it or map it or style it as per your requirement

Comment: how to make it work that every new text comes below the old one

Comment: I have updated the code at two places : first `setSomething(something.concat(<li>{input}</li>))` and second used `<ul>`